# JQuery UI Date Picker - Adding a class to all selected <td>

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to add a class to each `<td>` between two specific dates. Here is my code;

http://jsfiddle.net/7Q4Bt/171/

```
$(function() {

  $(".checkin-date__input").attr("placeholder", "mm-dd-yyyy").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "MM d yy",
        minDate: +1,
        showOn: "focus",
        numberOfMonths: 2
    }).on("change", function(e) {
        var curDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
        $(this).datepicker("setDate", curDate);
        if($('.checkin-date__input').datepicker("getDate")) {
            $( ".checkout-date__output" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", $('.checkin-date__input').datepicker("getDate") );
        };
    });

    $(".checkout-date__output").attr("placeholder", "mm-dd-yyyy").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "MM d yy",
        minDate: +1,
        showOn: "focus",
        numberOfMonths: 2
    }).on("change", function(e) {
        var curDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
        $(this).datepicker("setDate", curDate);
        if($('.checkin-date__input').datepicker("getDate")) {
            $( ".checkout-date__output" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", $('.checkin-date__input').datepicker("getDate") );
        };
        if($('.checkout-date__output').datepicker('getDate')) {
            console.log($('.ui-datepicker'));
            $('.ui-datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day').prevAll('td:not(".ui-datepicker-unselectable")').addClass('someClass');
        }
    });
```

The second input is limited by the date which is inputted into the first input.

Comment: I don't understand the question. It's only after the you pick the second date that you have a range of dates, but you'll also never see them again unless you change one of them. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Yes ..... I basically need to add a highlight class which will allow me to add a background to each td between the two dates.